# Dynamic database components with possible connections

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

Currently working on a new project, where different components can be entered and connected to eachother. The trick is that the amount of components and the data in a component can be anything, making it hard to find some sort of database-logic in it when it comes to table-setup and keys.

For example I have the following components:

```
cars
    name: audi, color: red, horsepower: 500
bicycle
    name: mybike, color: blue, lights: front and back
```

Etcetera. These components have some types in common, like name and color, but some different types, like horsepower on a car and lights on a bike.

These components can really be anything, but I need a way to link these together somehow in a database-structure that still makes sense.

Ive figured I could define a component-table that simply feeds an ID, with a seperate component-type table next to it per component. However that would require a different table everytime someone comes up with a new component (which again could be anything at any time).

I really do need to be able to structure these and link them together somehow, for example link that car to that bike.

Im running into a bit of a wall in my head thinking about this and hope someone can help me figure out how to do this in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open ended database model that fits this use case is the Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model. The problems that you encounter with this model are performance and complexity of queries. Now some DBs can assist you with pivot functions that will turn rows into column, but MySQL is not one of them. So if you go with this model then go with postgres as it has crosstab which will pivot the single row attributes of an entity into columns.

Comment: Sounds like what I need, I will dive into that link and set up a dummy. Can I ask you any further questions about this at that point should I have them?

Comment: Sure. We have had to use this model in some of our apps at work so I should be able to help you out.